# How to implement Many to Many LSTM architecture for numerical data (not timeseries , not NLP) in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034960/many-to-one-and-many-to-many-lstm-examples-in-keras), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63680986/what-is-the-correct-method-to-construct-a-many-to-many-lstm-model-using-keras-in)

I have numerical data in arrays of shape,

input_array =  `14674 x 4`

output_array =  `13734 x 4`

reshaping for LSTM (batch, timesteps, features) gives

input_array= `(14574, 100, 4)`

output_array = `(13634, 100, 4)`

Now I would like to build a Many to Many LSTM architecture for this given data,
should I use encoder-decorder or synced sequence input and output architecture

using following model but it works on when input and outputs are same

```
import tenowingsorflow
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Recall, Precision
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, Dense, MaxPooling1D, Flatten

opt = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)


model_enc_dec_cnn = Sequential()
model_enc_dec_cnn.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=9, activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 4)))
model_enc_dec_cnn.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=11, activation='relu'))
model_enc_dec_cnn.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model_enc_dec_cnn.add(Flatten())
model_enc_dec_cnn.add(RepeatVector(100))
model_enc_dec_cnn.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model_enc_dec_cnn.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4)))

model_enc_dec_cnn.compile( optimizer=opt, loss='mse',             metrics=['accuracy']) 
history = model_enc_dec_cnn.fit(X,y, epochs=3, batch_size=64,    )
```

Comment: but in seq2seq encoder-decorder we can have unequal input and output